# How to support choice for hold out/forecast period/window size in forecasting stock returns

Tags: forecasting

Are there any literature concerning what in-sample or out-sample period i should choose and how long the window should be when i consider a "moving window forecast"

Comment: A similar question has been asked here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1480/what-is-the-ideal-ratio-of-in-sample-length-to-out-of-sample-length The consensus there seems to be that there's no clear consensus regarding the IS/OS ratio.